# how do i change 24 fps to 60 fps without affecting the speed?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

i tried time remmaping but that messed up the keyframes and i really dont want to rekeyframe my animation. like when i set 24 fps to 60 fps and put 24 in old and 60 in new the speed is fine but the keyframes end way after. i dont have anything more to put here. this is all that i tried and i searched everything and found only a tiny bit of people who were in this situation.
edit: i'll explain it better. when i time remap my blender animation from 24 to 60 (old: 24 new: 60) and put framerate to 60. the speed is fine but the keyframes in the timeline get very desincronized (if thats how you say it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a time remapping option to remap your speed under the Render Dimension panel:

[image]

After the remapping, you need to calculate the **end** time by your self.

*And also, you can directly **"scale"** the animation inside your time line as you do in 3D View (press <kbd>s</kbd>)*. As 24 to 60, press 2.5 in your numpad should give you a correct result

The keyframe and animation is kind of complicate and give various option to tweak and customize the result. Give it a try and if still having problem, list more detail on what you've encountered with clear figure or good structured text description.